# "You have no fun." is this correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

So I was watching movies where I heard that sentence where a girl was tickling a boy.That boy then became annoyed and gave her a strong look which made her to tell "You have no fun".

Is that correct form of English or is there something missing that I still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Canadian, I would never use this - nor can I recall hearing it.  Do you recall the movie?  Perhaps it is a non-Canadian slang or (no offence intended) you misheard it.

It would make perfect sense in this situation to say "You're no fun!" (or "You are no fun!") or "(I'm) just trying to have a little fun".

You could also say "Can't you have a little fun?" but in that sense these are more common: "Don't be a stick in the mud", "Don't be such a (Debbie) downer", "You're a stick in the mud", "You're a real stick in the mud, aren't you?!", or the idiom "Someone got up on the wrong side of the bed!".

If you are annoyed, you could say (though it is a little vulgar and I would say it only to close friends) "Who ... in your corn flakes" - google search for "who" "in your corn flakes" to see it.

Comment: That means the subtitler was wrong .

Comment: Could be that the subtitler was incorrect, or (as I said) that the usage is common in another dialect / country